# Sending email in Sharepoint 2016 online without using workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, 2016

How to create and send email in sharepoint 2016 online without using workflows?

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you're trying to send. But as default - when outgoing e-mail setting is configured, users can subscribe to a list or library. When they do, and the criteria is met, an e-mail will be sent.

You can also share a website or add users to groups, and by that send an e-mail letting the added user know she is now part of that group.